# C++ Eigen throws error but finishes calculation

Tags: c++, matrix, runtime-error, eigen

I have this following code for a little ai using eigen but it has some wierd behavior when executed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

MatrixXd sigmoid(MatrixXd);
MatrixXd sigmoid_d(MatrixXd);


class Layer{
public:
MatrixXd layerweights;

Layer(int x,int y){
    layerweights.resize(x,y);
    for(int i=0;i<layerweights.rows();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<layerweights.cols();j++){
            double r =(rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)) * 2 - 1;
            layerweights(i,j) = r;
        }
    }
}
Layer(){
    this->layerweights.setZero();
}
};

class Network{
public:
Layer l1;
Layer l2;
MatrixXd inp;
MatrixXd outp;
int id;

Network(){
    id = 0;
    inp.resize(1,5);
    inp << 0,1,2,3,4;
    outp.resize(1,5);
    outp << 0,1,4,9,16;
}

MatrixXd think(){
    MatrixXd ol1 = sigmoid(inp * l1.layerweights);//1x5*5x5 1x5
    MatrixXd ol2 = sigmoid(ol1 * l2.layerweights); //1x5*5x5 1x5
    return ol2;
}



int main() {
Network generation [10];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){                     //initialize 1st generation
    generation[i].l1 = Layer(5,5);
    generation[i].l2 = Layer(5,5);
    generation[i].id = i;
}

for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
    cout<<generation[i].think()<<'\n';
}

return 0;
}

MatrixXd sigmoid(MatrixXd x){
return 1./(1+(x.array() * -1).exp());
}
```

the output in the console is:

Assertion failed: lhs.cols() == rhs.rows() && "invalid matrix product" && "if you wanted a coeff-wise or a dot product use the respective explicit functions", file c:\mingw\include\eigen\src/Core/Product.h, line 97

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

15.7222 7.48441 15.4497 8.88806 15.2964
8.90715  7.4913 4.46665 11.0792 9.32262
4.38281  5.5597 6.06866 7.33861  3.5983
5.69089 2.82105 8.79453  2.2928  7.4683
14.2536  5.6492 11.3739 11.9831 5.04955
9.85721 16.4741 4.57733 3.87002 2.37858

also it opens the gena_exe not working window (i work on a windows laptop).

the weird thing about it is that the prūogram is excuted to end and doesnt stop 
maybe it is just because my code is faster then the error handling
when the error occurs

Please help - thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it took me a second, but I found out what's happening: you create 6 generations in first loop `for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)` but iterate over 7 in next one `for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)`, so last call gets null matrix in `MatrixXd ol1 = sigmoid(inp * l1.layerweights)`

Change `i<=6` into `i<6` and there will be no crash.

But, the thing is, you could have found out it on your own very easly with help of debugger. It is really helpfull tool and the most of IDEs on Windows have one build in. I encourage you to start using it.

Also, as long as your program is single-threaded there is no chance for code to be "faster then the error handling when the error occur". Once you tried to do invalid mathematical expression Eigen asserted it and closed your program, but, whatever was already print to console sustained.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now i use the eclipse debugging tool